# PHPでxdebugを使ってブレークポイントでステップ実行をしたいです。

Tags: php, apache, vscode

phpのxdebugをVSCode上でインストールしました。ステップ実行をやりたいのですが、
ブレークポイントを置いてメニューからRun>Start Debuggingとしても処理を止めることができません。

現在の状況は、以下のようになっています。

１． xdebugの設定ファイル（launch.json）の
stopOnEntryをtrue (デバッグ開始時に最初の行で止まる設定）
pathMappingsを"${c:/Apache24}": "${c:/Apache24/htdocs}"

pathMappingsのc:/Apache24/htdocsに実行したいphpを置いています。

２．php.iniの設定（Dynamic Extensions）で、[xdebug.org](https://xdebug.org/download)からダウンロードしたxdebugのdllファイルを追加。

＜php.ini＞
zend_extension=xdebug-3.0.1-7.4-vc15-x86_64

xdebug-3.0.1-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dllは、
C:\php-7.4.13\extに置いています。
php.iniで
extension_dir = "C:/php-7.4.13/ext"
と設定しています。

１．のpathMappingsの設定は、{サーバー(=Apache)のパス}:{ローカルの実行リソースがあるパス}と思っているのですがそこが間違っているのでしょうか。

２．については、phpの拡張機能としてxdebugがあり、xdebugを動かすのに必要なdllを
C:\php-7.4.13\extに置いている、と思っています。
そのdllをphpの設定ファイルで有効化しているということになるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox内のBridge AdapterなVMとしてSElinuxをオフにしたLinux+Apache+php環境を用意し、
ローカル環境にVSCodeをインストールし、
VSCodeのワークスペースとサーバに同じソースを配置した状態から説明します。
なお、サーバ上のWebRootは/var/www/htmlと仮定し、
ブラウザからVirtualboxのipを入力し、phpのサイトが閲覧できる状態と仮定します。

【サーバ側の設定】

1. webサーバにxdebugを追加します。phpのバージョンやどこからDLするかは適宜調整してください。
2. 上記でapacheに設定ファイルも追加されたため、下記の個所を書き換えます。
3. webサーバの設定をリロードする必要があるため、再起動します。
4. 正常に再起動し、ローカル環境のブラウザからPHPサイトを閲覧できることを確認してください。

sudo yum -y install --enablerepo=remi-php72 php-pecl-xdebug

sudo vi /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "vscode"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host=<develop pc's IP>
```

sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

【VSCode側の設定】

1. PHP Debug拡張を追加します。
2. Webサーバ←→VSCode上で通信を行うのでウイルス対策ソフトのポートを開ける必要があります。
   　　（今回はWebサーバの設定ファイルで9000番ポートを指定したので9000を開けます）
3. VSCodeで初回デバッグするとどう初期化するかを聞かれるので、拡張でいれた内容を選択します。
   この時にVSCode環境にlaunch.json設定ファイルが存在しなければ自動生成されます。
   いったんデバッグは終了して、
   この生成されたjson設定ファイルを、以下のように書き換えます。
4. ブレークポイントを設置して再度デバッグを開始した後、ブラウザでphpサイトを閲覧します
5. ブレークポイントで処理が中段されることを確認してください。

launch.json

```
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```